# Hacked, is my IOS systems safe?Werid things?

Tags: multi-factor

I hope this finds you well.  I wanted to thank you in advance for your time and patience with me, and my questions.

I was Hacked by friends of an X-boyfriend from HighSchool.  He was a Foriegn exchange student from Sweden.  We have had some personal communications in the past one spanning 5 years of both of our lives.  In short on FB Messanger-I shared photos' with him,from Christmas.  Someone started trying to figure out who I was, etc..Jan 16/16-Feb 12/16 It literally broke me emotionally. Five emotional years,photos,chats,e-mails are now gone. Along with other things. I was never ransomed.

My Question is that things are showing up on my IOS devices that should not be. Like porn photos, I have traced it, back to what I think is the source of the photos, they do not know I am aware.

I will receive text messages "alledged" from mms I thought once to be safe.
MMS-776-836 asking me to call a number and what number to use on a Microsoft Account Security Code.  The creepiest one was the one I received on Easter Sunday, 2016 alleging that it was MMS-332-651
Facebook Safety
Check: Are you
Affected by the 
Explosion?

Reply SAFE if you're ok or 
OUT if you aren't in the area.

I asked my cousins if they had received a text message like this?

We were literally sitting down for lunch, when I asked.

I had/have been trying to reach my X in Sweden, to see if he knew.  I had left him my X-BF from High School(ah we are both past our 30's) a message via insta-account/the day before Easter, then the strange text from MMS 322-651, popped in to my I-phone. I was receiving MMS codes from 837-401, from Microsoft security alledged. One day it answered a question I expected to be answered via a Yahoo.com account, It said my Yahoo verification code is XXXXX, etc.  The next message received us what my Yahoo ID was or currently is. I have had previous Yahoo accounts, I wanted those as they have e-mails I needed.  It said under my Yahoo id, we.garon,Iburkett34???? I literally have to say Whiskey Tango Foxtrott or WTF..It is not making sense. I had to write 3 papers over and about Sweden during the attacks..My material kept getting removed. I went from an A to an F in the course of a week and a half.  I had to drop the class.  I am aware the first server farm outside of the United States, is in Lulea, se.  I am aware of the issue with Hackers in the general area, i.e. sweden.

I have Google verification codes coming from what I thought was a legit source MMS 256-447, then one popped in not hyper linked.

Look it I left myself open to the Hack. He had all my information from previously and current. I am positive they do/did not think I had a clue as to what was happening.  I was on the computer when the largest Hack came in, I physically saw my name being removed from e-mails..I have been researching all of this. I am  aware of what C-code was used, what free/open source it was pulled from, etc. They left digital fingerprints every where.  Can you Help me? I am not stupid, however there is only so much I can do here in the U.S..I respectfully ask for your assistance with all of this Crazy, literally a heart breaking mess.  Someone on here may have helped these people out trust me I am not mad at anyone (I would really like to know why?)...I just need some clarification as to what is legit. What is not legit. Who(m) or What to trust.  Is my cell phone 
I-6 clear or not? Is my I-pad clear or not?

Sincerely, 
Amy M. Bearden

Comment: This does sound like a case of identity theft rather than actual device breach. If your iOS devices are not jail broken, that would be the first breach I knew of.

Comment: I realize this question is rather lengthy, but other than that why was it put on hold?  I believe it falls in the following categories listed in the help center: incident response physically securing information assets, network security, and social engineering.  Can someone please state definitively and specifically why this question was closed?

Comment: Brent - this type of question is not answerable here. There are multiple, possibly unrelated questions, for a start, the post is rambling, with very little useful information. It doesn't matter if the core topic is within our site scope if the question is not, and without being able to conduct forensics, it is not possible to answer why an attacker does anything. (It's also not useful to guess)

Comment: @RoryAlsop  I can understand if the question(s) at hand are rather broad and the situation not described clearly.  Likely this is a lay person try to get an answer to a question they are not even sure how to ask.  I suggest we try a soft approach in these cases, since they may not even know the language to ask the questions they have.

Answer (score 4):

As helphul as it might be for you to figure out the motivation behind all of this, **that is nothing we might help you with.**

As far as the breach of your system goes:

- A lot of online identities seem to be affected and compromised.
- Your computer seems to be [not you computer anymore](//meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/988/92273).

There are several things we cannot help you with:

- If you linked your iOS device with the computer that is no longer yours, a jailbreak and following up an infection might have happened.

  Detecting wether that is the case or not is not easiliy possible remotely.
- If you linked any cloud services to the identities that have been compromised with your iOS device, photos, documents, contacts,... might (dis)appear at any time.

  Precious data should be backed up already. If that's not the case, there is little hope such data can be rescued.

There are several steps to take:

1. Check for infections across your network (router?)
2. Secure your network
3. Nuke all your infected devices from orbit
4. Regain control over all compromised identities by reaching out to their customer service
5. Use strong passwords, do not reuse passwords

Side note:

Note that this is not a forum but a Q&A site. Please read [ask] and do not use comments for extended discussions.

Answer (score -3):

I am truly sorry.  Unfortunately a problem like this takes a lot of elbow grease and persistence to clean up.

Laptops are generally easier to clean up than cell-phones.  If you find security consultant or even a very good IT person, they can probably help you with the laptop.  The phone might be a loss, as it might be jailbroken (jailbroken means that third-party, non-Apple, software can be installed on the machine).  If the phone is only jailbroken, it can sometimes be repaired by resetting the firmware.  However, it seems that a severely compromised phone will just need to be replaced.

If you are badly hacked, you will need to do a security audit of all the electronic devices in your life, including your car and wifi routers.  You will also want to audit the security of all your online accounts, but only after you have established one safe computer to work from.  Until you have a safe computer to work from, you should leave your online accounts untouched.

The main reason to do audits is to assess the extent of the damage and to repair the security of the devices and accounts.  In the past it was sometimes feasible to simply replace the most effected device, but today hackers leap from machine to machine across a network and usually can hack new, clean machines until the whole network is cleaned up.  This means that all the devices in your life need to be returned to a more secure state.

Your description of the situation sounds remarkably bad.  Please consider getting professional computer help.  Please consider getting emotional support from friends during this difficult time.  Please consider reporting this to law enforcement.